# The 'pwd' command take much time cost after read a big file(eg:40M)

Tags: python

The following python code contains three processes :

- Process 1 : Call `connect_machines()` (Actually do pwd command)
- Process 2 : Call `get_machines()` (Actually read a big file)
- Process 3 : Do the same thing as phrase 1

The process 3 time cost is much bigger than process 1

The `conten_big.txt` file is a file with json datas, it's size  is `39M`.

When I run the `main()` function， the value of `end_time2 - start2` is `22.04s`， and the  value of `end_time1 - start1` is `08.51s` .

When I commentted  the `#machines_a = get_machines()` line, and then run the  main function, the  value of `end_time1 - start1`  is almost equal to  `end_time2 - start2`

```
import sys
import pdb
import os
import json
import time
import datetime
import logging
import commands
def get_logger(logger_name):
    """configger the logger """
    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO, \
            format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
            datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',
            filename='./log/%s.log' % logger_name,
            filemode='w')
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    return logger

logger = get_logger('test_log')

def get_machines():
    print 'get machines start'
    fp = open('./conten_big.txt', 'r')
    machines = fp.read()
    fp.close()
    machines = json.loads(machines)
    print 'get machines have finished',len(machines)
    return machines

def connect_machines(loop_count):
    for idex in range(0, loop_count):
        connect_port(idex)

def connect_port(idex):
    ret2 = 0
    cmd = 'pwd'
    start_time=datetime.datetime.now()
    (status, msg) = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    end_time=datetime.datetime.now()
    cost = str(end_time-start_time)
    logger.info("[%d] --[%d] -- [%s] %s" % (idex, status, msg, cost))

def main(argv):
    """main """
    nowTime=datetime.datetime.now()
    print nowTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    machine_count = 5000

    logger.info("=====================>>>>")
    start1=datetime.datetime.now()
    print start1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    connect_machines(machine_count)
    end_time1=datetime.datetime.now()
    print end_time1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    logger.info("[%s] --- [%s] ---[%s]" % (end_time1, start1, end_time1 - start1))
    print end_time1, start1, end_time1 - start1
    #read one big file, eg. a file size 39M
    machines_a = get_machines()
    logger.info("=====================")

    time.sleep(30)

    start2=datetime.datetime.now()
    print start2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    connect_machines(machine_count)
    end_time2=datetime.datetime.now()
    print end_time2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    logger.info("[%s] --- [%s] ---[%s]" % (end_time2, start2, end_time2 - start2))
    print end_time2, start2, end_time2 - start2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: What question do you mean to ask?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your program takes time is because the file has a big size (~40MB), as you have previously stated that commenting `get_machines()` reduces the execution time significantly.

Comparing `end_time1 - start1` with `end_time2 - start2` does not make sense because a for loop with only 5000 iterations is way much faster than reading a very big file, with a lot of binary data that take much longer to process.

Comment: Actually,  "end_time1 - start1" and "end_time2 - start2" are both time cost of 5000 loop, but  the time cost is so different. the second one is after reading a big file

Comment: @fucheris Yes thats because the file is big.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm confused how reading a large file can affect the for loop time cost

Comment: It does not affect but you are reading the file after the loop so the total time cost is the time spent by the loop plus the time spend by the file